# io: ios app development option greyed out

Tags: ios, keychain

I just signed and created a certificate with keychain access, then in the developer portal I click certificates->developer->+ and when I am prompted for What type of certificate do you need? under development ios app development is greyed out.

Does any one know why this is? Do I need to revoke a certificate?

[image]

Comment: Have you signed up for the iOS Developer Program and payed your $99 yet?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: Yes I'm logged into dev portal

Comment: @Undo screen shot uploaded

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Figured it out.

1. Revoke all developer certificates.
2. Click certificated again to refresh

Works!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But can you tell me why it happens?

Comment: Sometimes the certificates expire and you have to reset all of them. I dont know why apple wont let you reset just one of them.

Comment: I only need to revoke one among two. So probably there's a limit to the number of development certificates one can have.

Comment: I revoked one of the certificates but "iOS App Development" is still disabled. There's only three left and I don't want to remove them. What is "certificated"--do you mean the plus sign to add a certificate?

Comment: This works, but this is super frustrating. My developer certificates were not even expired and I had to delete them all just to generate another one.

Comment: @Phil  I agree with your situation, Do you find any solution? I also dont want to delete all certificate and I also have three certificate remain in account. Previously I have 7 certificate and I revoke 4 but remaining three I dont want to revoke. Do you find any another solution?

Comment: @sinh99 After three yeas I honestly don't remember how I got passed the problem, only that somehow, I did.

Answer (score 34):

You can only request one development certificate per user.
Either log in as the user you want to request a certificate for, or remove the existing certificate(s) for the user you are logged in as. **No need to delete everything.**

Comment: This is the correct answer, you do not need to revoke all certificates

Comment: Whats defined as a user? I have a 99$ Dev account. Can I have more than one user and do they each need their own certificate or same 1 from this category?

Answer (score 10):

Nowadays iOS App Development option is getting greyed out don't know why.

Even I had this situation and I solved it (made it enabled) using the following steps.

1. Remove the expired development certificates from Certificates/Development.
2. Revoke the unused development certificates.
3. Now click on the + button and you are free to select the

   iOS App Development option.

Answer (score 2):

If am correct you can only request one development certificate per user.

Answer (score 0):

from IOnic help document through CLI option: 
http://docs.ionic.io/v2.0.0-beta/docs/ios-build-profiles

Try with below option : 
Create the p12 Certificate using OpenSSL

Download your iOS certificate to the same directory as your private RSA key. We'll need it to create the Certificate.p12 file.

First, we need to change the format of the iOS certificate to PEM.

Shell :

openssl x509 -inform DER -outform PEM -in ios_development.cer -out ios_development.cer.pem
Now that the iOS certificate is in the proper format, we can create the Certificate.p12 file.

Shell :
openssl pkcs12 -export -inkey keyname.key -in ios_development.cer.pem -out Certificate.p12

You will be prompted to enter a password, which will be used to protect the exported certificate. Give it something you can remember!