# I cannot create more than one Development Certitifcate in iOS developer certificates

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate

I am having lots of problems with certificates and provisioning profiles like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16269072/io-ios-app-development-option-greyed-out) question, trying the solution never helped.

I just had one Development Certificate and I cannot longer create more.

I try all solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2177143/how-to-renew-an-iphone-development-certificate) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15979924/how-to-request-ios-development-certificate-in-2013), also I've try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18786540/cannot-find-option-to-create-ios-app-development-certificate) one, I am the Admin, so this is not my problem.

If you came with a solution I am open to try everything because I am kind of desperate.

Waiting for your answers

Comment: There can be only one developer certificate for each developer member.

Comment: I have two developer members. The admin one and another admin, should I turn the second admin into member?

Comment: If the second admin is also a developer, you could create a separate dev certificate by logging on with his account.